# Is there a way to clear the message below the command line (zle -M "message") if a different widget runs?

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

I have a zsh/zle widget that is usually/often run multiple times in a row. I would like to display a message using `zle -M` but if a widget *OTHER* than mine runs I would like to clear the message. Is there a way to do that?

I've poured through the docs but I don't see a hook or anything else to pull this off. The only thing that occurred to me is replace every key binding that bindkey reports with a head patch wrapper and then restore them if it gets hit but I think that would cause problems with widgets who look at `$WIDGET`, `$LASTWIDGET`, etc.